# struts2 xml validation to match strings

Tags: struts2, xml-validation

I want to perform a string match validation using the struts2 xml validation. This is the kind of xml rule I am trying to write:

```
<validator type="expression">
    <param name="expression"><![CDATA[ (str1.indexOf(str2) > -1) ]]></param>
    <message key="message.key.text" />
</validator>
```

When I try to run this it I get the below warning message and the validation does not work:

```
Got result of [(null)] when trying to get Boolean.
```

Is there some restriction on what operations can be used in struts2 xml validation expressions. equals() and equalsIgnoreCase() seem to work so I assumed that indexOf would also work. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Post examples of what expressions are working and ones that not.

Comment: Use `fieldexpression` for that. Also you are not checking for null-s.